# INSERT not working if not done in phpmyadmin / linux mysql client

Tags: c++, mysql

i have a table called functions :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `functions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `couple_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `src_1` text,
  `src_2` text,
  `percent_1` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `percent_2` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_functions_couples1` (`couple_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=73193 ;
```

I'm performing a Transaction query looking like the following:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `functions` (`couple_id`, `name_1`, `name_2`, `percent_1`, `percent_2`, `src_1`, `src_2`) VALUES ("8510", "borwein_integer", "calc", "83", "100", "static double    borwein_integer(double n, double x)
{
  double        k;
  double        result;

  k = 0;
  result = 1;
  while (k <= n)
    {
      if (x)
        result = result * (sin(x / ((2 * k) + 1)) / (x / ((2 * k) + 1)));
      k = k + 1;
    }
  return (result);
}
", "double              calc(double i, double n)
{
  double        k = 0;
  double        res = 1;

  while (k <= n && i != 0)
    {
      res = res * sin(i / (2 * k + 1)) / (i / (2 * k + 1));
      k++;
    }
  return (res);
}
");
...
COMMIT;
```

(Of course, i'm doing a lot of stuff in this transaction, but i just wrote these `...` to simplify the problem).

When i run the query using phpmyadmin or mysql (under linux), the query works.

But if i use it with [mysql_real_query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-query.html), it throws an error like this :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'INSERT INTO `functions` (`couple_id`, `name_1`, `name_2`,
> `percent_1`, `percent_' at line 2

How i call `mysql_real_query`:

```
  this->log(query.toString());
  if (mysql_real_query(this->_bdd, query.toString().c_str(), query.toString().size()) != 0)
```

(The `log` function displays the query exactly as i did write it above).

I've been using [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) to figure out my problem, but i did not change anything... The error is still the same.

Does anyone have an idea about what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: See the page you're linkning to yourself: 'Normally, the string must consist of a single SQL statement without a terminating semicolon (“;”) or \g. If multiple-statement execution has been enabled, the string can contain several statements separated by semicolons'. It looks like multiple-statement exec is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from the mutliple-statement execution (as stated in the doc, this must be enable).
Have you tried executing only the INSERT statement with mysql_real_query ? This will give you an idea of whether the issue comes from the INSERT statement or the mutliple-statement execution.

Comment: The query was working before i changed it to a transaction... I did as specified in the procedure from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html to solve my problem.

Comment: Show your C++ code that enables `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`. @GeoffreyB